# How to close (kill) ssh ControlMaster connections manually

Tags: ssh, connection-sharing

With the following `.ssh/config` configuration:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist 4h
```

How to close the persisting connection before the 4 hours?

I know you can make new connections, but how to close them (all)?

Maybe there is a way to show all the persisted connections and handle them individually but I can not find it.

Comment: Not killing it, but you can simply *not use* the persisting connection via `ssh -S none` (maybe this helps you already).

Comment: No I'm trying to remove a user on a remote server, but the hanging connections prevent me from doing it.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh):

> `-O ctl_cmd`
>    Control an active connection multiplexing master process.  When
>    the `-O` option is specified, the `ctl_cmd` argument is interpreted
>    and passed to the master process.  Valid commands are: `check`
>    (check that the master process is running), `forward` (request
>    forwardings without command execution), `cancel` (cancel
>    forwardings), `exit` (request the master to exit), and `stop`
>    (request the master to stop accepting further multiplexing
>    requests).

Older versions only have `check` and `exit`, but that's enough for your purpose.

```
ssh -O check host.example.com
```

If you want to delete all connections (not just the connection to a particular host) in one fell swoop, then `fuser /tmp/ssh_mux_*` or `lsof /tmp/ssh_mux_*` will list the ssh clients that are controlling each socket. Use `fuser -HUP -k tmp/ssh_mux_*` to kill them all cleanly (using SIGHUP as the signal is best as it lets the clients properly remove their socket).

Comment: In OS X `fuser` can't send signals, but this works just as well: `lsof -Fp /tmp/ssh_mux_* | cut -c 2- | xargs kill -HUP`

Comment: Just to make this extremely clear since it tripped me up: `host.example.com` is the part after the `@` when you ssh. You have to leave out your account name.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote an open source utility, [`cmc`](https://github.com/ClockworkNet/cmc), to manage ControlMaster sessions: [ClockworkNet/cmc](https://github.com/ClockworkNet/cmc):

```
Usage:  cmc [ -c HOST | -o HOST | -x HOST ]
        cmc [ -L | -l | -O | -X ]
        cmc -h

ControlMaster Controller - Eases management of SSH ControlMaster connections

Options:
    -h      show this help message and exit
    -c HOST check HOST ControlMaster connection status (maybe specified more
            than once)
    -L      list ControlMasters defined in SSH_CONFIG
    -l      list ControlMaster connection sockets in ~/.ssh/ and check their
            connection status
    -O      open all ControlMasters defined in SSH_CONFIG
    -o HOST open a ControlMaster session (maybe specified more than once)
    -x HOST close ControlMaster session (maybe specified more than once)
    -X      exit all ControlMaster connections with sockets in ~/.ssh/

Notes:
    * Any unopened sockets in ~/.ssh/ are removed with -l and -X
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me using just the socket file for the control master:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/<controlfile> -O check <bogus arg>
```

#### Example

Here's an example where I've already established a connection to a remote server:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check blah
Master running (pid=89228)
$
```

And with it disconnected:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O check blah
Control socket connect(/Users/user1/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74): No such file or directory
$
```

If it were still connected, this would force it to exit immediately:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O exit blah
Exit request sent.
$
```

It's unclear to me, but it would appear to potentially be a bug in `ssh`  that it requires an additional argument at the end, even though `blah` is meaningless in the context of the switches I'm using.

Without it gives me this:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

#### Version info

*OSX*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
```

*CentOS 7.x*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

I confirmed that on both of these versions, the need for the additional bogus argument was required.

#### References

- [How to tell if an ssh ControlMaster connection is in use](https://serverfault.com/questions/211213/how-to-tell-if-an-ssh-controlmaster-connection-is-in-use)
- [How to exit OpenSSH control master process without using lsof or fuser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459450/how-to-exit-openssh-control-master-process-without-using-lsof-or-fuser)

Answer (score 3):

You can run `fuser /tmp/ssh_mux_blablabla` (possible needing `sudo`) and kill the PID it returns. `fuser` shows which processes are using a file. (And more, check out `man fuser`.)

Update: check out Gilles' answer; it is much more detailed.