# How to exit OpenSSH control master process without using lsof or fuser?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is there a more direct way to exit an *OpenSSH* control master process and delete its socket file than with the help of the programs `lsof` or `fuser` **and** without knowing the *destination* host (connection details) as suggested by the accepted answer of this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/how-to-close-kill-ssh-controlmaster-connections-manually)? I thought of something like this along the lines of:

```
$ ssh -O exit -S ~/.ssh/7eb92b0827f3e8e1e8591fb3d1a5cd1b94b758cb.socket
```

I'm asking because I'm looking for a scriptable way to exit every open control master connection each time when I log out of my user account. Not doing so causes my *sytemd*-powered *openSUSE* computer to wait for a timeout of two minutes until it forcefully terminates the still open control master connection powering off eventually.

Unfortunately *OpenSSH's* client program `ssh` requires the *destination* host and the `ControlPath` file name pattern in order to deduce the actual file path to the socket file. I on the contrary thought of the more direct method of providing the concrete socket file via the program's `-S ctl_path` option.

In the global section of my system-wide *OpenSSH* client config file I configured *OpenSSH's* connection multiplexing feature as follows:

```
ControlMaster auto      
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%C.socket
ControlPersist 30m
```

Please note that I want to keep the file name pattern for socket files, i.e. hashing the token string `%l%h%p%r` with the token `%C`.

Any ideas?

Comment: @slm: I was already aware of the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/how-to-close-kill-ssh-controlmaster-connections-manually but it doesn't suffice my needs. I therefore chose a very specific title for this question. Basically how to accomplish closing an _OpenSSH_ control master connection without `lsof` or `fuser`. Maybe I should have further restricted it to _without knowing the destination host_ (connection details).

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, see A'er.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me using just the socket file for the control master:

```
$ ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/<controlfile> -O check <bogus arg>
```

**NOTE:** You can also use `ssh -S ~/.ssh/<controlfile> ...` as well, which is a bit shorter form of the above.

#### Example

Here's an example where I've already established a connection to a remote server:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check blah
Master running (pid=89228)
$
```

And with it disconnected:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O check blah
Control socket connect(/Users/user1/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74): No such file or directory
$
```

If it were still connected, this would force it to exit immediately:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-66496a62823573e4760469df70e57ce4c15afd74 -O exit blah
Exit request sent.
$
```

It's unclear to me, but it would appear to potentially be a bug in `ssh`  that it requires an additional argument at the end, even though `blah` is meaningless in the context of the switches I'm using.

Without it gives me this:

```
$ ssh -S ~/.ssh/master-57db26a0499dfd881986e23a2e4dd5c5c63e26c2 -O check
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

#### Version info

*OSX*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
```

*CentOS 7.x*

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

I confirmed that on both of these versions, the need for the additional bogus argument was required.

#### UPDATE #1

I [raised this as a potential bug to the OpenSSH](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2889) upstream and they replied as follows:

> Yes - this is intentional.
>
> ControlPath may contain %-expansions that need a hostname to expand fully.
>
> We could conceivably check to see whether ControlPath actually needs this and make the hostname optional but 1) ControlPaths that use %h are common and 2) I'd rather not make the argument parsing code more of a maze than it already is.

#### References

- [How to tell if an ssh ControlMaster connection is in use](https://serverfault.com/questions/211213/how-to-tell-if-an-ssh-controlmaster-connection-is-in-use)
- [How to close (kill) ssh ControlMaster connections manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/how-to-close-kill-ssh-controlmaster-connections-manually)

Comment: The host argument at the end tells `ssh` what ControlMaster socket to remove if the ControlMaster is set up in a `.ssh/config` file. I could do `ssh myhost` (which sets of a ControlMaster socket) and later `ssh -O exit myhost` while still having other sockets active for other hosts in my configuration file.

Comment: Right, that's was the feedback I received and what was described in the scenario form the upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility that eases management of SSH ControlMaster connections. It's called **`cmc`**:
[TimidRobot/cmc: ControlMaster Controller - Eases management of SSH ControlMaster connections](https://github.com/TimidRobot/cmc).